# ¿Se puede hacer una consulta de la base de datos en tiempo real?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Lo que quiero es poder consultar la base de datos en tiempo real, no sé cómo puedo hacer que cuando se añada alguna fila a la base de datos, se edite o elimine, no tenga que recargar para poder verla sino que aparezca inmediatamente. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer eso?

```
<?php 

if($db){

  $consulta2="SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE titulo  = '".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC";
  $resultado2 = mysqli_query($db, $consulta2);
  if($resultado2){
      while($row2= $resultado2->fetch_array()){
  $sq = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$row2['usuario']}'";
    $ru = mysqli_query($db, $sq);
 $ro = mysqli_fetch_array($ru);
  $photou = $ro['photo'];
          echo "

           <div style='height: 7%;'></div>

          <div id='container'>

           <a href='profile.php?user={$row2['usuario']}'><img id='ph' src='images/users/$photou'>
          <div> {$row2['usuario']} </a> <eti>{$row2['mensaje']}</eti>



        </div></div>";
      }
  }
}

   ?>
```

Comment: Ajax debería ser la opción a utilizar

Comment: Es precisamente lo que hace ajax se ejecuta en segundo plano y permite realizar consultas(peticiones) sin recargar pagina.

Comment: Aparte de ajax podrías utilizar websocket, que para lo que quieres hacer es lo más adecuado.